# Make a Label and Text (Discount) appear in report when the number (more than 0) enter at form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I had some difficulty to make the VBA or macro to do this function. basically, I'm making an MS access for sale service system and the system required of the discount section. the concept is when the user enters the percentage of discount in form site and also appear in the report when the percentage is 0, the system will hide the discount label.

I try using some VBA code such as

```
Private Sub txtDiscount_Click(txtDiscount As Integer)
    If Me.txtDiscount.Value = 0 Then
        Me.lblDiscount.Visible = False
    Else
        Me.lblDiscount.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

but I don't how to make it work when press F5 it pop up macro name. I'm request expert to solve my problem. may show me some step to execute the VBA.

Comment: Not sure in Access, but in Excel UserForm, you should be putting event on `txtDiscount_Change` for the discount label to show/hide automatically: `Me.lblDiscount.Visible = (Me.txtDiscount.Value > 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

In a form, it would be something like this:

```
Private Sub txtDiscount_AfterUpdate()

    Me!lblDiscount.Visible = (Me.txtDiscount.Value > 0)

End Sub
```

In a report, you could use the *Format* event of the section of the report where the label is located.